# Diagnosing a SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: c#, wcf

```
var client = new CommonClient()
XElement exceptionDates = XElement
    .Parse(client.ExceptionDatesUpdateControl("status").OuterXml);
```

When  calling:

```
client.ExceptionDatesUpdateControl("status")
```

The following error is thrown:

> SecurityNegotiationException: A Call to SSPI Failed

What is the cause?

Additional information:

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICommon" />
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>      
      <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/service/common" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICommon" contract="Service.Common.ICommon" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICommon">            
      </endpoint>
    </client>
```

App.config:

```
<services>
      <service name="PROJ.Service.CommonService" behaviorConfiguration="CommonServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>            
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/service/common"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>            
        <endpoint
             address="net.pipe://localhost/service/common"
             binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="pipeCommonServiceBinding"
             contract="PROJ.Service.ICommon"
             />
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.securitynegotiationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> This exception can happen in the following cases:
>
> • While negotiating
>   the initial security context. The exact error depends on the
>   negotiation technology used: either Simple and Protected GSS-API
>   Negotiation (SPNEGO) or TLSNEGO. For more information, see Security
>   Protocols.
>
> • While establishing a security session on top of an initial security
>   context.
>
> • During key renewal for an existing security session.
>
> Security negotiation errors can occur as part of the Spnego/Sslnego
>   security protocol or as part of the SecureConversation protocol.

source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.securitynegotiationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> I found the answer.
>   When I looked deeper, there was another exception:
>   "Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException".
>
> It disappeared when I commented these lines in my config file:

```
 <!--identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/..." />
    </identity-->
```